# Optimistic concurrency with EF Core 2 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimistic-locking, ef-core-2.0

With EF Core 1 I used uint property for concurrency checks, cofigured this way:

```
entityBuilder.Property(e => e.ConcurrencyStamp)
    .ForNpgsqlHasColumnName("xmin")
    .ForNpgsqlHasColumnType("xid")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

With EF Core 2 there is not `ForNpgsqlHasColumnName` nor `ForNpgsqlHasColumnType` methods. How can I accomplish the same functionality using EF Core 2?

Comment: See if [Optimistic Concurrency and Concurrency Tokens](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/misc.html#optimistic-concurrency-and-concurrency-tokens) helps. Or in case you don't support multiple database types, use the common `HasColumnName`, `HasColumnType` etc.

Comment: Thank you for hints and the link, i haven't seen it before!